# what are the major advantages of using variable variables in php?

Tags: php, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's an actual use of variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523670/whats-an-actual-use-of-variable-variables)

i saw the concept of variable variables in php .
that is a variable whose name is contained in another variable .

like this

```
$name = ’foo’;
$$name = ’bar’;
echo $foo;
// Displays ’bar’
```

one advantage that i see is , you can create variable names with numbers or lettes which you can not use normally . like this

```
$name = ’123’;
/* 123 is your variable name, this would normally be invalid. */
$$name = ’456’;
// Again, you assign a value
echo ${’123’};
// Finally, using curly braces you can output ’456’
```

and also you can call some functions like this

```
function myFunc() {

echo ’myFunc!’;
}
$f = ’myFunc’;
$f(); // will call myFunc();
```

and in a book i saw this

> Variable variables are a very powerful tool, and should be used with
>   extreme care, not only because they can make your code difficult to
>   understand and document, but also because their improper use can lead
>   to some significant security issues.

The problem i have is if using variable variables in the code can be that dangerous . why are we using it . and is there any major advantages using variable variables in my code , if any what are those advantages .

Comment: They are great to confuse other programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it in case of not-user-input. Look

```
function getVar($gid){
    $name = "gid".$gid;
    global $$name;
    $var = $$name;
    return $var;
}
```

It's useful when you have a lot of variables (same start with ending number, etc...) which is probably save

Answer (score 1):

Look at your example:

```
function myFunc() {
echo ’myFunc!’;
}
$f = ’myFunc’;
$f(); // will call myFunc();
```

It is powerful: `$f` can have a value dynamically and the function called based on this value.

At the same time: If the user was given limitless access to `$f` this could be a security threat

Answer (score 1):

In some MVC Frameworks they use it to run a function which will vary depending on the URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/thecontroller/theaction
```

in PHP side they will parse the url, get the second segment which is the name of the function then run it, but how? they will assign to a variable like what you have mentioned:

```
$toRun = 'theaction';
$toRun();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used double and even treble indirect pointers in C, but have never explicitly used variable variables in PHP (but I have used variable functions and classes).

I think it's somehow reassuring that there's more functionality in PHP than I use - and that I can make informed choices about which constructs I do use (I often use explicit references for example).

Answer (score 0):

A nice usage I saw in some framework is using them to access, easier, values passedfrom another script as an array:

```
$array['test'];
$array['other'];
$array['third_index'];
// or simply $array = array('test','other','third_index');

foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
  $$k = $v;
}
```

So you could then have `$test`, `$other` and `$third_index` being usable as variables. Pretty handy when dealing with views, for example.

Comment: errr.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php ?

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but tell the CodeIgniter team ;)