# When to use PHP's variable variables?

Tags: php, php-7, interpretation

I've been using PHP for some basics Back-End development for a while now. I saw something about interpretations of variables while I was looking for some changes which came with PHP 7. I'm not using them and it would be great if someone can explain **why to use them**?

What I mean is:
[image]

What are the **pros of using them**?

Comment: Variable variables (`$$foo`) are almost always a bad idea. Variable property access (`Foo::$bar`) can have its uses. You'll realise that when you encounter a situation where it's beneficial. Listing arbitrary situations in which it can be useful is a bit aimless and broad for an SO question.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the term "interpretation". The manual refers to that as [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

Comment: Alright, I didn't realize that it's that broad. I'm deleting the "when" question and will just stick to the "why" part of it. Thank you.

Comment: Just found you took that table from the PHP/7 migration guide ([Backward incompatible changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect)). There isn't any PHP feature called "interpretation", it just means that PHP parser now evaluates certain expressions in a different order.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I couldn't find it in documentation as I was looking for the "interpretation" keyword from the image above. I'll probably change the title here.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523670/whats-an-actual-use-of-variable-variables)

Comment: I personnaly like to use them to make my code cleaner and more intuitive when treating forms. See a [demo here](http://phpio.net/s/2e6f).

Comment: @Gradiuss Beware that your example basically recreates [register_globals](http://php.net/register_globals), an infamous PHP feature that made it easy to get your site hacked. You can also use [extract](http://php.net/extract), which can be nearly as bad.

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález, I'm aware that this can lead to security breach. When I say *I personnaly like to use them*, I mean that this would be for me one of the use case, but in reality I don't because of those security issues. Of course, dynamic variable car most of the time be avoided with a little more code understanding in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use variable interpretation in situations when you need to dynamically reference a variable and don't want to use an array. Generally I would not recommend using it, as you lose benefits such as static code analysis.

Comment: Can you please provide us with some example maybe? Thank you.