# for loop check if empty value in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, is-empty

In PHP I have 3 fields. I want to only output fields that have a value using a loop.

```
$field_1 = "john";
$field_2 = "";
$field_3 = "jack";



for($a = 1; $a <= 3; $a++)
{
$fieldOutput =  '$field_' . $a;
    
    if (!empty($fieldOutput)) {
    echo $fieldOutput;
}
}
```

My desired output is:
john
jack

...but the code above outputs `$field_1`. I'm looking to output the actual value of the field though.

...how please can I amend the for loop code to achieve that.
Thanks

Comment: What you're looking for is a variable variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593055/variable-variables-in-php-what-is-their-purpose and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523670/whats-an-actual-use-of-variable-variables

Comment: Or use an array and `array_filter()` (with some minor warnings about what filtering actually removes).

Comment: Better off using an array `$field[1]`  then you can access `$field[$a]` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line `$fieldOutput =  '$field_' . $a;` with `$fieldOutput = ${"field_$a"};`. See the [PHP documentation for variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 1):

Explain:
Solution:
First create of array of all variables. then iterate that array.

```
<?php
$field_1 = "john";
$field_2 = "";
$field_3 = "jack";

$data=array($field_1,$field_2,$field_3);
for($a = 0; $a < count($data); $a++)
{

    if($data[$a]){
        echo '<br>'.$data[$a];    

    }

}

?>
```